# How can display dynamic urls in Nuxt.js with DRF

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

I just got an answer on how to bring information from DRF to display on the [last thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536792/how-can-fetch-data-in-nuxt-js-on-drf). I want to know more.

I tried following the guide to the basics. But still don't understand Anyone have a way to solve this problem?

I just want to do Dynamic Pages.https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing-dynamic-pages

How do I get it to be displayed? tree path is

**pages**

-- _catname

---_product.vue

index.vue

_id.vue

Sorry for asking a lot I'm really a beginner

My _product.vue

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <h1>CAT NAME: {{ catname }}</h1>
    <h2>Product ID: {{ id }}</h2>
    <p>Path: {{ $route.path }}</p>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to All Product</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, redirect }) {
    const products = await fetch(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_api/api/v1/Product/'
    ).then((res) => res.json())

    const filteredproducts = products.results.find(
      (el) =>
        el.catname === params.catname &&
        el.id === params.id
    )
    if (filteredproducts) {
      return {
        catname: filteredproducts.catname,
        product: filteredproducts.name
      }
    } else {
      redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and my _id.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ this.id }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   async asyncData({ params }) {
      const id = await params.id // When calling /abc the slug will be "abc"
      return { id }
    }
  }


  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this` keyword in template.

Also let us know what's the error for you and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
├─Pages
    ├────index.vue
    ├────_product.vue
    ├────_catname.vue
    ├────_id.vue
```

Assuming you have above file strcture. In that case `_product.vue` have only param-`product`. Hence, product can be filter by `params.product` only.
here is the code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>CAT NAME: {{ catname }}</h1>
    <h2>Product ID: {{ id }}</h2>
    <p>Path: {{ $route.path }}</p>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to All Product</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, redirect }) {
    const products = await fetch(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_api/api/v1/Product/'
    ).then((res) => res.json())

    const filteredproducts = products.results.find(
      (el) =>
        el.id === parseInt(params.product)
    )
    if (filteredproducts) {
      return {
        catname: filteredproducts.catname,
        product: filteredproducts.name
      }
    } else {
      redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i will try, but not show anything and redirect to root pages.

Comment: what are you getting in `products` variable

Comment: "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "catID": "TOO08",
            "catname": "เครื่องมือช่าง",
            "sku": "1690",
            "name": "เส้นเอ็น SL NO.50",
            "brand": "ระกา",
            "price": "40",
            "detail": "เส้นเอ็น SL NO.50",
            "imgurl1": "****",
            "imgurl2": "****",
            "productclick": "*****"
        },


like this.

Comment: product name is in local language and i guess you getting `param.product` in english

Comment: i try to filter by  el.id === params.product but a same

Comment: what are you getting on `params.product`

Comment: i think you getting `id` in `params.product`. try this `el.id === parseInt(params.product)`, it should work..